# A Simple input/output query of C++

Tags: c++

I have to take this as input:

> 3
>   sam
>   99912222
>   tom
>   11122222
>   harry
>   12299933

So, I wrote down the following code:

```
string s;
int num,n;
cin>>n;
while(n--){
    getline(cin,s);
    cin >> num;
    cout << "s=" << s << " num=" << num << endl;
}
```

So, Expected output should be:

> s=sam num=99912222
>   s=tom num=11122222
>   s=harry num=12299933

But output is:

> s= num=0
>   s= num=0
>   s= num=0

Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*One* problem is that the `cin>>n;` statement to get the count leaves the newline in the input buffer. So when you then call `getline` it will see that newline and think you entered an empty line.

Then it gets worse when you try to read the number, as the next text is *not* a number, it's the name, and trying to read it as a number will set the [`failbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate).

A standard solution is to [ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) characters until the newline, which will skip the rest of the line including the newline character. So do something like

```
std::cin >> n;
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

You of course need it after the other input too.

Comment: @RahulJain No. First of all `stdin` and `std::cin` are not connected, they have different buffers. Secondly, doing `fflush` on `stdin` is technically *undefined behavior*. While some libraries support it, it's not something you should get a habit of doing if you want to be portable.